# VK.NET получает неполный список аудиозаписей

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте! Я пытаюсь получить список аудиозаписей из своего плейлиста Вконтакте с помощью VK.NET, используя метод [Audio.Get](https://vknet.github.io/vk/audio/get/) следующим образом:

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<Audio> GetAudios()
{
    User user;
    var audios = currentApi.Audio.Get(out user, new AudioGetParams {
        NeedUser = false,
        Offset = 0
    });
    MessageBox.Show("Найдено " + audios.Count + " аудиозаписей");
    return audios;
}
```

И на всякий случай метод авторизации:

```
public static void SignIn(string login, string password)
{
    // ID приложения, через которое будет осуществляться авторизация.
    ulong appId = ********; 
    // Необходимые для работы приложения разрешения.
    Settings settings = Settings.Audio;
    // Авторизация на сайте.
    currentApi.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
    { 
        ApplicationId = appId,
        Login = login, 
        Password = password, 
        Settings = settings 
    });
}
```

Проблема: метод возвращает не все аудиозаписи из списка, хотя они не являются изъятыми и отлично находятся с помощью [официального API](https://vk.com/dev/audio.get). Максимальное допустимое возвращаемое количество аудио (6000) тоже не превышено. В комментариях по ссылке на VK.NET люди пишут, что у них та же самая проблема. Может быть, кто-нибудь может объяснить, в чём загвоздка и как с ней бороться?

Comment: Ну, если тут и есть человек, знающий почему либа VK.NET возвращает не полный список записей, то он либо разработчик VK.NET либо дернул с гитхаба исходники VK.NET'a и разобрался как там работает метод получения списка аудиозаписей. 
Полагаю, что VK.NET это не более чем обёртка над стандартным API. Значит либо старое API используется, либо уже на уровне VK.NET'a происходит дополнительная фильтрация (маловероятно что явная, скорее всего неявная (баг) при десериализации получены данных ) 
Если ответа никто не даст - лучшее решение - заглянуть в исходники VK.NET

Comment: Проблема несколько интереснее: Поковырял исходники VK.NET. Вытащил из него строку запроса: http s://api.vk.c om/method/audio.get?offset=0&v=5.53&access_token=/*токен*/ 
где все параметры кроме access_token необязательные. Причём у меня тоже возвращает count=38 и при этом в item'ах всего 10 объектов....
А как выглядит строка запроса при использовании "официального API"?

Comment: Имелось в виду, что по ссылке на официальное API внизу страницы есть возможность протестировать метод, вот там список аудиозаписей вытаскивается без пропусков :)

Comment: тестер, судя по всему, использует данные о авторизации в браузере и, с точки зрения сервера, это веб версия. А значит ограничений нет.  Теоретически можно попробовать поковырять страничку с этим тестером дабы вытянуть с неё строку запроса которая уходит на сервер. Но, сдаётся мне, скрипт там обфусцирован, а трафик шифрован. А так теоретически приложение могло бы прикинуться браузером...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ службы поддержки ВK ( Не моё, нашёл на просторах ):

> Некоторые записи по просьбе правообладателей доступны только в
>   веб-версии и официальных приложениях.
>
> С уважением, Агент

Соответственно средствами api.vk.com данное ограничение не обойти. Опять же на просторах сети пишут, что данное ограничение успешно обходится с использованием прямой авторизации ( https://vk.com/dev/auth_direct ) Причём те же авторы утверждают что, опять же на просторах, возможно найти необходимые для данной авторизации данные и не морочится с подачей заявок и т.п.

Так что вам либо смириться, либо реализовать (хотя бы на основе исходников того же VK.NET) свой вариант либы для работы с VkApi который в некоторых случаях использует прямую авторизацию.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать так

```
var audios = vkApi.Audio.Get(new AudioGetParams
            {
                OwnerId = vkApi.UserId.Value,
                Count = 6000
            });
```

Может вам поможет. Максимальное количество 6000. Если у вас элементов меньше, тогда должен вернуть весь список.